# How to construct a conditional running average with 3 weeks prior to the condition?

Tags: r, moving-average, promotions

I have the following sample df, consisting of a category (**Cat**) in which different **articles** are shown (Pizza or Pasta) together with their **sales** data for different calender weeks (**CW**). In some weeks there is a **promotion**, which causes the sales to go up. The 6 largest sales values are marked as such promotions.

```
# example df
set.seed(99999)

df <- data.frame(Cat = rep(c("A","B"),52),
                 Article = rep(c("Pizza","Pasta"),52))
df <- df[order(df$Cat),]
df$CW <- rep(1:52,2)
df$sales <- abs(2+rnorm(104))
df$promotion <- ifelse(rank(df$sales,ties.method=c("last"))>98,1,0)
```

The challenge now is to **calculate a "baseline" against which to judge the promotion**. The baseline needs to meet the following requirements:

- per article and category, three weeks prior to the promotion need to be calculated as the baseline
- the baseline should be "running", i.e. there should be a baseline for every calender week
- within the three previous weeks for baseline construction, there must be no promotion. If there is, that particular week is ignored and the more previous one is taken until a week with no promotion is found and three weeks are achieved. If this should not be possible, e.g. CW 1-3, then the next future baseline value is taken

I have tried solving this challenge using existing [posts on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743812/calculating-moving-average) , but with no success. Hence I am asking for help.

Comment: Dear @Ronak Shah, would you be able to help me with this one? I really appreciated your help on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883566/how-to-fuzzy-join-2-dataframes-on-2-variables-with-differing-fuzzy-logic) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with **dplyr** and **zoo** could look like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df2 <- df %>%
  arrange(Cat,Article,CW) %>%
  group_by(Cat,Article,stimulus) %>%
  mutate(Baseline=rollapplyr(sales,list(-(3:1)),mean,fill=NA))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(Baseline=ifelse(stimulus==1,lead(Baseline,n=1L),Baseline))
```